# How to populate and maintain listView with images?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, imageview

I want to design a listView such that when a user adds a photo, it will automatically update the listView with the name of the image and it's thumbnail. However my current attempts don't even render the image. Is it possible to dynamically set the ImageView for each cell of a listView and have it be updated when I add a new element to the Adapter?

XML for listView and add button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".Photos"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/view_album_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <ListView android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:id="@+id/photos_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/add_photo_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/plus"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity:

```
    public class ViewAlbum extends AppCompatActivity {
        public Album activeAlbum;
        private ListView photoList;
        private ArrayList<String> currentPhotos = new ArrayList<String>();
        private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
        private int currentSelected = -1;
        public static final int PICK_IMAGE = 1;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.view_album);

            final Context context = getApplicationContext();
            Toolbar albumBar = findViewById(R.id.view_album_bar);
            setSupportActionBar(albumBar);

            photoList = findViewById(R.id.photos_list);
            Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
            String albumName = bundle.getString("album_name");
            activeAlbum = Album.loadAlbum(this.getFilesDir().getPath()+"/"+albumName+".txt");
            for(Photo photo: activeAlbum.photos){
                ImageView thumbnail = findViewById(R.id.photo_thumbnail);
                if(thumbnail == null){
                    System.out.println("why?");
                    //Don't understand why it is null, can't set image
                }
                currentPhotos.add(photo.name);
            }
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.photo_cell,
                    R.id.photo_name,currentPhotos);
            photoList.setAdapter(adapter);
            photoList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    currentSelected = position;
                }
            });
            FloatingActionButton addPhotoBtn = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.add_photo_btn);
            addPhotoBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
                }
            });
        }
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK
                    && data != null && data.getData() != null)  {
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                Photo newPhoto = new Photo("name", uri.getPath());
                activeAlbum.photos.add(newPhoto);
                activeAlbum.saveAlbum();
            }
        }
```

Each ListView Cell:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/photo_thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="106dp"
            android:layout_height="77dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/photo_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text="Album Name"
        android:textColor="#0984e3"
        android:textSize="25dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I think `album.photo` is not the same array as the array you passed when you create the adapter (`currentPhotos`). So adding new Photo to album.photo does not reflect that item in the listView.

Secondly, as user dev points out, whenever you change the data you need to tell the adapter by `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. However in your case, you always add to the end i think it is better to call `adapter.notifyDataInserted(currentPhotos.size() - 1)`

Comment: Okay that makes sense, but I still don't understand why:

ImageView thumbnail = findViewById(R.id.photo_thumbnail);

is null, where ever I call it.

Comment: This is because the `R.id.photo_thumbnail` does not exist in your XML files for MainActivity. It only exist in XML for the items, so you cannot access it from MainActivity. Instead, updating ListView items should be done within the adapter. To implement this you'd probably have to create an Adapter class inheritting from ArrayAdapter and provide some public method to update the thumbnail. Hope I make sense.

Answer (score 2):

When you get result on OnActivityResult() add it to currentPhotos,
then call notifyDataSetChanged()

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with images which are locally stored or on the web. Using a lib like `implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'` is probably a good idea as it can handle image and URL based exception and had a catch of the data so that it is easier to open apps memory can be used minimally.